# How to know the user's system user id in php?

Tags: php, mysql

I am making a web app, I have done the front-end and currently working on the back-end with PHP.

I have three tables in my database:

1. `user - user_id,name,email,verified`
2. `password - id,user_id,password,time,method`
3. `meta - id, user_id, at1, at2`

Now, the values in the 'user' and 'password' tables are stored when the user registers. Values in 'meta' table are to be stored later.

Now, when the user is logged in and it's time to save the values in 'meta' table, how do I know the particular `user_id` of the user?

I have tried using `$_SESSION['user_id']` which gives an error
and I have tried `$user_id = mysql_insert_id()` which doesn't works out correctly.

What's the correct way to do this?

Comment: You are not setting the necessary values into the session when a user login.?

Comment: You get the user_id the same way you get name, email, verified and other information. Select the column using a SELECT query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you logged in use;

```
$_SESSION["user_id"] = $user_id; // taken from db
```

And be sure that, you have started session before assigning;

```
session_start();
```

After that, you can use this session value in pages you want